# Black Screen when looking at specific things in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Every-time i shoot something with a spectral arrow in Minecraft, my screen goes completely black but only when i'm looking at the thing i shot, if i look away my screen is normal again but when i try to look at the mob i shot then it goes black again. The same thing also happens in the map '*CUBE FACTORY: THE COLOURS*' at the boss fight.

Please someone help, I've tried to look it up but i don't think anyone else has this problem.

Comment: If the answer helped you, please mark it as accepted. If it didn't, please give more details.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like something like this happened before, as reported in the [Mojang Issue Tracker](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-100969). Basically, you should:

1. Update your graphics driver. [Adobe has a article that can help](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/update-graphics-driver-windows-7.html).
2. Reinstall Minecraft.